# External forces acting on two blocks attached with inextensible string and on a surface with friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

> Two blocks of masses $2$ kg and $4$kg are connected through a massless inextensible string. The coefficient of friction between $2$kg block and the ground is $0.4$ and the coefficient of friction between $4$kg block and the ground is $0.6$. The forces $F_1=10N$ and $F_2=20N$ are applied on the blocks as shown in the figure. Calculate the frictional force between $4$ kg block and ground (Assume initially the tension in the string was zero just before forces $F_1$ and $F_2$ were applied)

[image]

**My attempt:**

After reading Ankit's answer, I realized that it is incorrect to consider that the whole friction force to be in effect. Now I compare the friction and external force to figure out if the system external force exceeds the 'friction capacity' of the system. The total friction which could act is given by:

$$ F_{\text{frict} }  = .6 \cdot 4 \cdot g + .4 \cdot 2 \cdot g =24 + 8 =32N$$

**The total force applied is:**

$$ F_{drive} = 20 -10 =10N$$

Obviously, the system doesn't move.. but I'm not quite sure what to do here.

---

**Solution given in the book:**

In the solution I found online for this problem, they took the system as if it was in equilibrium and assumed that maximum static friction acts on the left block. **I'm trying to figure out why they considered maximum static friction to act on the left block and then  used that to find forces on the 4 kg block**

Also **what do they mean by the last statement** " (Assume initially the tension in the string was zero just before forces $F_1$ and $F_2$ were applied)"?

The final answer is supposed to be 18N

Comment: How did you interpret the last sentence in parentheses?

Comment: I couldn't quite figure out what they were going with that so I didn't comment on it

Comment: @Buraian why did you take $F_{drive} = 20+10$ ?

Comment: You should focus more on the concepts. Giving all of your attempts and searching for a solution definitely makes this more of a "check my work" question. The exercise should be a context, not the focus.

Comment: @Ankit Nice catch, I have fixed that now

Comment: I couldn't figure it out either that's why I asked.

Comment: It sounds like they are saying the string is in tension before F1 and F2 are applied.

Comment: @BobD  I searched the question and found a source saying to consider tension before as zero before applications of forces.

Comment: @Ankit Kindly see the edit

Comment: @BioPhysicist I tried to format the question quite a bit

Comment: Ok, but I can't really tell what you want to know here other than "how do I solve this problem, am I trying to solve it correctly?'

Comment: @Ankit The source I had taken the question from seemed to have skipped a small detail, I have added it in. So, I'm saying that you should consider that as well.

Comment: @Buraian if the source said it was zero before F1 and F2 are applied, then maybe the last sentence should have has the word  "zero" after the word "was". In any case I don't see how it could be in pre-tension if the string is inextensible. Like a spring could be in pre-tension because it is extensible.

Comment: @Ankit exactly, also maybe an explanation on what they mean by last sentence would also help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to figure out why they considered maximum static friction to act on the left block and then used that to find forces on the 4 kg block

**For $2kg$** :

What is the magnitude of the external force acting on the $2kg$ block ?

It is $10N$ and the maximum static friction that could act on it is just $8N$ , so we must consider this exact value of static friction force when the external force exceeds this value to know about the net force (since tension came into action after the external force was applied).

**For $4kg$** :

The external force is $20N$ and the maximum static friction force that could act is $24N$ which means that in this case the friction force will not have its maximum value . Had the external force be greater than $24N$ then the friction force would be $24N$ otherwise not.

You should consider the equation of motion for the $2Kg$ block first because in this method you know the exact friction and using this you can calculate tension but if you take the equation of motion for the $4Kg$ block then you will have to calculate two variables (friction and tension) with just one equation which I think can't be done.

And for that last statement , though it is not so clear but I think the string was very close to being taut and came into action after the external forces were applied. So, this is the reason why tension served in the equation of motion of $2kg$ block  and we took the maximum static friction force into account for the $2kg$ block.

Hope it helps ☺️.

Comment: you haven't discussed the part near end of question "In the solution I found online for this problem, they took the system as if it was in equilibrium and assumed that maximum static friction acts on the left block. I'm not sure why the maximum static friction happens on the left block or how they concluded it was in equilibrium."

Comment: Well you could start at the right block as well. The friction is 24N but the block has force 20 applied to, hence only 4N goes as tension.. so why the preference to the block on left?

Comment: @Buraian I have edited my answer. Hope it is clear. Also if you want to know how to proceed from your equation you can ask me in the chat.

Answer (score 1):

As you showed, the maximum frictional forces are enough to counter the external forces, so the center of mass of the system is definitely not moving. Since the string is inextensible, this means that the two blocks can't move in the opposite direction either. So the only natural thing to assume is that the blocks are at rest.

For the first block to be at rest, the forces must be balanced. Let $T$ be the tension and $f_1$ be the frictional force then:

$$10=T+f_1$$

Now here comes the last sentence into play: "Assume initially the tension in the string was zero just before forces F1 and F2 were applied)"

What it means is that, before we applied the external forces, the string was completely relaxed. It was not exerting forces on the masses at all.

Now ask yourself..when would tension start coming into play? It's when the string would try to stretch. If friction alone would do the job of stopping the block, then no tension needed for the string.

Here, the external force on the left block is 10N, while the max friction possible on that block is only 8N. So if we had applied 8N or lower, there'd be no tension needed to balance that. Here, friction provides 8N, and then the string tries to stretch. Since the string is inextensible, tension provides the rest 2N to keep the block at rest.

Now that you know that the tension is 2N to keep the left block at rest, use the equilibrium of the right block with this known tension to get the answer

Comment: "If friction alone would do the job of stopping the block, then no tension needed for the string." The force of block is less than friction which can take before it starts moving

Comment: " So if we had applied 8N or lower, there'd be no tension needed to balance that. ".. didn't get this

Comment: Still haven't explained why we are taking left block I think

Comment: @Buraian The tension only comes into play when the string tries to stretch. If the irregularities of the ground already provide enough force to keep the block from moving at all, then the string can't even begin to stretch (hence no tension). Since friction can provide upto 8N of force on the left block, no tension would've arised in the string if the applied force on the left block was 8N or lower.

Comment: @Buraian We are solving for the left block because it allows us to solve for tension as the friction force on the left block is a known maximised value (max static friction) On the other hand, the friction on the right block could be anything. Any combination of forces $Friction+Tension=20N$ would keep the right block at equilibrium. You can't solve for two unknowns from one equation

Answer (score 1):

**Reference pic**:

[image]

We can see on the 4kg block, the applied force is less than the maximum static friction of it(24N), and on the 2kg  we can see that the applied force is more than the static friction(8N). However, this block does not seem to move, why?

This because there is the constraint of the string. If the block on 2kg starts moving to the left then the block 4kg block will follow its lead to keep the length of the string constant (inextensible string).

Now, the residue force (*) on the 2kg block will be canceled by the 4kg block through the means of tension through the rope. On the 4kg block, the difference between applied force and friction will be taken care of by the friction on that block(18N). In a way, we can think of friction as being transmitted over the string.

---

*: the difference between the applied force and tension

Answer (score 0):

### for 4kg block

we see that max friction that can act on this block is $0.6mg$

---

I.e 24N which ensures that the right block will remain at rest (obviously because tension is also opposing the motion )

### now the 2kg

Max frictional force is 0.4mg I.e 8N which means the system might move if tension force< 2N so we assume that the system won't move( we do this because it is easier to check this way)

---

In this way tension is 2N the same tension on 4kg . We will check whether this force is able to stop the 2nd block also
Putting $T=2N$ we get to know that only 18 N friction is required to stop the block which is less than limiting friction this means our assumption that 2kg block will not move is right

---

Note# if our assumption was wrong the tension force would have come large enough such that the right block would have moved to the left which is not in this case

Comment: I apologise for my mistake but I didn't downvote.

Comment: So, you're saying to assume the situation and work on that? If this is the case can you show how it leads to problems if we assume the opposite scenario?

Comment: @Buraian it's not possible to solve that way as then I would have got two variables tension and acceleration so I chose the easier path:)

Answer (score 0):

> In the solution I found online for this problem, they took the system
> as if it was in equilibrium and assumed that maximum static friction
> acts on the left block. I'm trying to figure out why they considered
> maximum static friction to act on the left block and then used that to
> find forces on the 4 kg block

The maximum static friction happens first on the left block because the maximum *possible* static friction force on the left block is less than the right block, so it has to be reached first before any impending motion is theoretically possible. But the left block can't move unless the right block moves also because they are connected together. That would require the static friction force on the right block to also equal its maximum possible static friction force. But you have already shown that even if both static friction forces were at their maximum, the two block system wouldn't move. From this, one can only conclude that the system is necessarily in equilibrium.

Now, given the 2 block system system is in equilibrium and that the static friction force on the left block is its maximum static friction force (8 N), you can draw a free body diagram (FBD) on the entire 2 block plus string system. The external forces acting on the system are F1, F2, the maximum static friction force on the left block 8 N, and the unknown static friction force on the right block. The tension in the string is an internal force so it is not part of the equation. The sum of all the external forces is then zero for equilibrium. That will give you the static friction force on the right block. As you already know, it will turn out to be 18N.

> Also **what do they mean by the last statement** " (Assume initially
> the tension in the string was zero just before forces $F_1$ and $F_2$
> were applied)"?

Its not clear exactly what they had in mind. Maybe they wanted to tell you not to consider the possibility that the string was in pre-tension before F1 and F2 are applied. Pre-tension could be created if, for example, the left block was on the surface while the right block block is pulled while not on the surface, creating tension in the string and then placed back on the surface to maintain the tension. But I really don't know.

Hope this helps.